# Ionic React app is overlapping with Android status bar

Tags: android, ionic-framework

In my Ionic app, the top portion is being overlapped with the android status bar. I've tried setting variable.

```
safe-area-inset-top
```

to 32px; but that only works for my Android Pixel 3a. On my Pixel 6, since the status bar is bigger than the Pixel 3a's, the safe-area is not enough.
Is there any better solution other than fixing safe-area-inset-top to a specific number?
Thanks

```
"@capacitor/android": "3.4.3",
"@capacitor/app": "1.1.1",
"@capacitor/core": "3.4.3",
"@capacitor/haptics": "1.1.4",
"@capacitor/ios": "3.4.3",
"@ionic/core": "^6.2.9",
```

Tried

```
safe-area-inset-top
```

but it only worked for a specific device.